# What would be $\left(\mathbf{v} + \mathbf{u}\right)^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Say you have two vectors $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{u}$.

How would you solve

$$ \left( \mathbf{v} + \mathbf{u} \right)^2?$$

As far as I know, vector multiplication has dot product and cross product, so would we use

$$ \left( \mathbf{v} + \mathbf{u} \right)^2 = \mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{v} + 2\left(\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{u}\right) + \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{u},$$
or 
$$\left( \mathbf{v} + \mathbf{u} \right)^2 = \mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{v} + 2\left(\mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{u}\right) + \mathbf{u} \times \mathbf{u}?$$

Or does it depend on whether we want a scalar or vector value as our result?

Comment: Use the dot product. If $\mathbf w$ is a vector (in your example, $\mathbf{w=u+v}$), then $\mathbf w^2$ is defined to mean $\mathbf{w \cdot w}$.

Comment: Note that $v\times u\neq u\times v$!

Comment: Note also that $v \times v = 0$

Comment: Terminology point: "solve" should normally only be used for (in)equations. You can say "solve $3x+2=0$ (for $x$)" or "solve $A\mathbf{u} = \mathbf{v}$ (for $A$, given $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$)", but "solve $(\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{u})^2$" is essentially the same as "solve $2$": there is nothing to solve for. The verb you want is "determine" or "compute".

Answer (score 1):

As $\cos0=1$, you can write $(v+u)^2$ as:
$$(v+u)^2=(v+u).(v+u)$$

Let
 $v=v_1\hat{i}+v_2\hat{j}+v_3\hat{k}$..........(i)

$u=u_1\hat{i}+u_2\hat{j}+u_3\hat{k}$........(ii)

Then, $(u+v)^2=v.v+v.u+u.v+u.u=v.v+2(u.v)+u.u$
You can even substitute values of v and u given by equations (i) and (ii) respectively

Comment: u an d v are vectors, I couldn't write them in bold letters because of math error.